# Luacode in NewDocumentEnvironment problem

Tags: xparse, luacode

I want to put some systematic code at beginning and at the end of a luacode environment.

Why this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,luacode}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{LTG}{%
        \begin{luacode}
    }{%
        \end{luacode}
}

\begin{document}

essai

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\NewDocumentEnvironment` needs at least an empty `{}` argument specifier -- this is missing in the OP.

The classical `\newenvironment` does not require the classical argument specifier brackets `[]` at all, it can be omitted then.

The error here would occur with basically any code following the environment name bracket, i.e. `{LTG}`, making `xparse` believe, that `\begin{luacode}` is the argument specifier, which must fail here of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,luacode}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{LTG}{}{%
 \begin{luacode}
 }{%
  \end{luacode}
 }

\begin{document}

essai

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't ask whether the `luacode` inside such an environment is useful at all ;-)